# Postfix, setup SMTP for hosted websites

Tags: email, postfix, ubuntu-14.04

I have a VPS which hosts different domains, and I'm trying to setup SMTP with postfix, so the users can send emails via SMTP from addresses like:

```
user1@site1.com
user2@site1.com
user3@site2.com
```

I managed to configure tsl, sasl etc. but I can't find how to configure the smtp accounts... All the guides I can find use a UNIX user to login, which is not what I'm looking for...

To receive mails, I'm currently using the `virtual_alias_maps` to forward incoming mails to the respective owner mailbox.

Comment: How will `userx` be able to see his mails if he does not even exist on the server?

Comment: Do you want `user1` to receive his mails locally i.e. at `user1@site1.com` or at his personnal address i.e. at `user1@outside`?

Comment: I want user1 to send, not to receive, an email using his email client, and that email must show user1@site1.com in the From: header

Comment: Hence this isn't a `server` side configuration problem, but rather a `client` side one. You can't achieve this through a `Postfix` rewriting since this E-mail will most probably not even go through your `Postfix` server. ---- I suggest you to rewrite your question so as to avoid useless answers as mine :(.

Answer (score 1):

Use `canonical` to rewrite sender adresses as for example:

1. Within `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

   ```
   canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
   ```
2. Within `/etc/postfix/canonical`:

   ```
   user1   user1@site1.com
   user2   user2@site2.com
   ```
3. Then run:

   ```
   postmap canonical
   postfix check
   postfix reload
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use virtual mailbox. This is done normally with a database. In database are stored virtual accounts with directory specified where e-mail should be stored. Then IMAP/POP3 server (Dovecot) can provide access to e-mails stored on server.

For more information try searching for: "dovecot postfix virtual mailbox"
For example read this:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin

Comment: Do I have to setup the imap/pop3 server even if I just need to SEND mails, not receive?

Comment: This depends how you authenticate senders. You always may let them send whatever they want without authentication. I think standard postfix setup does that in most Linux distributions.